# Is there a way to load a variable page with a java <%@ include?

Tags: jsp, include, server-side, include-path, server-side-includes

I would like to do something like:

```
<%@ include file="links/"+linkFile %>
```

Is there any way to do something like this? It's for a jsp page, but I don't want to use `<jsp:include>` because I want access to all the information on the parent page.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "all the information on the parent page"? That makes it sound like the page is architected kinda funny.

Comment: Basically it's a page that loads a bunch of data and then there are pages the formats the data. One of the pieces of data that gets loaded is which layout file to use, which determines the output of the page.

Comment: And you're dead-set on not using scoped variables? Static includes are a PITA for multiple reasons; it's really not that common of a technique.

Comment: I don't think I know how to use scoped variables in the way that you're implying. I'm not classically trained in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: No.

See [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/IncludesActionDirective) for a comparison between them. [This thread](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-java-programmer/562267-using-variable-within-jsp-include-directive.html) has more details regarding why what you want to do isn't possible (and a potential reason *why* you're trying to do it like that ;)

It sounds like the pages were architected "PHP-style". In a *clean* JSP site most of the dynamic work is done in Java code, generally a servlet or framework-specific class (action, controller, whatever).

When I say a "scoped" variable, I mean an attribute in the page, request, session, or application context. In this case you'd probably just put things in the request scope so they'd be available everywhere that has access to the current request.

Once a variable is in scope in can be retrieved using JSP EL syntax, like `${myVariable}`.

Without more details it's difficult to know what the best way to go about cleaning things up would be.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would like to speak with you about how this would be done with the work being done with the java code. It's something I strive to do, but I can never figure out how to load the pages dynamically with java without using a variable. I can't figure out how to privately message someone on here.

Comment: @PixMach The easiest thing to do would be to create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and mention me on Twitter; if it's something I can answer in a reasonable amount of time I'll probably get back to you.